# website/app that's centered on sharing data between users and devices

Tags: web-applications, bluetooth, mobile-website

quick question that I hope has a straightforward answer, I'm beginning to build a website that's driven by sharing data. Bluetooth is an aspect of it for local communication between users and devices. My question is, before beginning the website do i need to take into account bluetooth when programming or can i simply program my site and then worry about the bluetooth sharing functionality afterwards? Just trying to be safe than sorry, i'd imagine I can focus on the site first and then add worry about the bluetooth. However, what if i'm wrong and not considering some key part in the designing of the site that'll shoot me in the foot.

I might be worrying too much but since i'm not experienced, i'm here asking those who are. Thank you for the help with the question!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. I think this question is too general to be accurately answered on this site. Fundamentally, you should be able to develop the site and have bluetooth interaction added later, but how easy this is is very dependant on what frameworks and languages you use. I suggest doing some more research into what your options are for bluetooth interaction (libraries, packages, etc) in your language(s) of choice and you should be able to identify what frameworks they will suit well. If not, come back and ask once you have narrowed it down some more. Hope that helps!

Comment: makes sense, thank you! i'm using rails as the framework. I'm using extensive tutorials and online guides to help me with the project. However having no prior experience with back end or front development, I wasn't sure if I perhaps needed a more specific framework to approach that bluetooth question.